# how to read xml file in native android app with phone gap

Tags: android, xml, cordova, custom-error-pages

I have a file `app.xml` on my website like [this](http://www.domain.com/android_apps/app.xml). I want to build native android app with phonegap. how can I read the `XML` from my website to build online native application? kindly give me code how can I read the `XML` in my native android app. I'm very thankful to you for this.

I'm beginner developer of phonegap android application developer. I'm in confusion. I want to make a photo gallery that work online(with internet).

1. how can I embed my photo gallery with the application?
2. if user connection lost during checking photos is there a way to not show error page on my app (`could not find URL http://www.domain.com/app/index.php`) after connection lost it will go to on default error page of no internet connection.

my online application is in php how can I `<iframe>` that app in my native application.

phonegap android application developer help me. I'm very thankful to you for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery parese. this url well help you:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time). Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.